# Fabric (Canvas) on Mobile Devices while page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I observed that we are not able to scroll web page by swiping fingers on mobile devices where we have used Canvas linked to Fabric covering full screen.

problem i due to canvase not allowing page scroll how can i fix it.

url : http://dev-shree.com/sendfile/

please check in mobile view.

Is there any way to fix it .

my code for canvase defination :

```
(function(global) {

    "use strict";
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{selection : false,controlsAboveOverlay:true,centeredScaling:true});
    var overlayimageurl = $('#myimg').val();
    canvas.setOverlayImage(overlayimageurl, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    canvas.stateful = false;
```

Comment: what is `after_submission`? it should be some function defined to handle this hook, can you share link of the post?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve scrolling on both the page and the canvas? I would suggest adding a small toolbar at the top instead when in mobile view.

Comment: You edited your question and now it is totally a new question. You should not have done that. Rather you should ask a new question. Now my answer makes no sense with your current question. So i rolled back your changes. Please post a new question without editing this one

Answer (score 21):

fabricjs canvas class has `allowTouchScrolling` option `Indicates whether the browser can be scrolled when using a touchscreen and dragging on the canvas`

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',
    {
        selection : false,
        controlsAboveOverlay:true,
        centeredScaling:true,
        allowTouchScrolling: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Khawer. This helped me alot

Comment: How can I achieve pinch to zoom with fabric js?

Comment: this is not working in my project, I am using fabricjs canvas under iFrame.

Answer (score 5):

What Tim Hill has said is correct. allowTouchScrolling: true, seems to do nothing. If you add pointer-events: none; to upper-canvas and lower-canvas, you can affect the ability to scroll the page while touching the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

pointer-events: none;

will disable other events on canvas

Comment: could you please explain your answer a bit

Comment: could you please explain your answer a bit

Comment: you will be able to scroll the canvas, but drag object on canvas will be disable , in your case may be you can build a function to change css , in my case it dose't help

Comment: Is it possible to have `pointer-events: none;` only on the background? In this case, it would be possible to zoom the whole page when touching the background, and zooming objects when touching objects: http://fabricjs.com/touch-events

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by implementing the above AND
ensuring all FabricJS objects (upper-canvas, canvas element, lower-canvas) had the CSS;

pointer-events: none;

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If any issue with page scrolling you can use this one in your CSS file :

```
canvas { 
    z-index: -1111;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All credit to @wnbittle and @alexey-altteam for their answer on the [github issue#5903](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5903#issuecomment-699011321). Worked for me with fabricjs 4.2.0.

Add this function at the bottom of the fabric.js file:

```js
(function(){
  var defaultOnTouchStartHandler = fabric.Canvas.prototype._onTouchStart;
  fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Canvas.prototype, { 
    _onTouchStart: function(e) { 
      var target = this.findTarget(e); 
      // if allowTouchScrolling is enabled, no object was at the
      // the touch position and we're not in drawing mode, then 
      // let the event skip the fabricjs canvas and do default
      // behavior
      if (this.allowTouchScrolling && !target && !this.isDrawingMode) { 
        // returning here should allow the event to propagate and be handled
        // normally by the browser
        return; 
      } 

      // otherwise call the default behavior
      defaultOnTouchStartHandler.call(this, e); 
    } 
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the scrolling issue for me for fabric 5.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2 or higher then you should update the fabric js.

[image]
Source: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/pull/5904/commits/50962efe6bbd77174cda2e9bd169c19d301edb7a

Then use `allowTouchScrolling` option.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',
    {
        allowTouchScrolling: true
    }
);
```