# Zooming on background and zooming on Fabric JS objects

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I like what I obtain on mobile with touch events on Fabric JS: http://fabricjs.com/touch-events

On mobile, I can pinch zoom on each object and make it bigger or smaller. Though, if there are many objects, it is really difficult to do it properly.

**I would like to be able zoom the whole page by pinching on the background and still be able to zoom on objects**. A bit similar to what I would obtain if I did the following:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',
{
    selection : false,
    allowTouchScrolling: true
}
);
```

plus adding to `canvas`,`upper-canvas`, and `lower-canvas` the following CSS: `pointer-events: none;`. As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546028/618091

Unfortunately, of course all objects become unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that the option `allowTouchScrolling: true` works. You might have to remove `(e.preventDefault();)` in the `_onTouchStart` function as suggested here https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5903#issuecomment-693416109

Then, you can define the following two functions:

```
var disableScroll = function(){
  canvas.allowTouchScrolling = false;
};

var enableScroll = function(){
  canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true;
};
```

If a `target` is defined, it means the click didn't happen on the canvas background. Thus, the following works:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  if (options.target) {
    disableScroll();
  }
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', enableScroll);
```

Some more references:
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/1864#issuecomment-112361190
[fabric.js: bind event to background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903219/fabric-js-bind-event-to-background-image)